# Tomcat 6 ignores external connections

Tags: tomcat, connection, localhost

I have downloaded Tomcat 6.0.36 windows service installer and install it using "Minimum" type of installation. After that I launched Tomcat service.

localhost:8080 works properly, i see Tomcat's welcome page

192.168.1.131:8080 works fine too (from local machine, 192.168.1.131 is it's lan address)

but from another machine in my lan 192.168.1.131:8080 are not opening!

Ok. Also I have an eclipse with Run Jetty Run plugin installed. I stop my Tomcat service and start jetty server from eclipse on same 8080 port. And vua-la!

192.168.1.131:8080 works from another machine in my lan.
That is why I rule out routing/firewall errors.

I tested it with two different machines on Win7 as Server's.

I also tried to switch on tomcat's acess log, but nothing interesting in it, there is now requests from external machine.

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot! And sorry for my ugly english=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to go to

```
Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Firewall\Allowed Programs
```

and check whether the tomcat exe is allowed